# Apache Ignite 2.7.5: server crash with "NoClassDefFoundError: sun/nio/ch/Invoker$2"

Tags: java, ignite

For the current moment, this error occurred only once. Ignite starts with one node in server mode and about 30 in client mode.
In the server's log, I found this stack trace:

```
Failed to reinitialize local partitions (rebalancing will be stopped):
...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/nio/ch/Invoker$2
...
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeIndirectly(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl$ReadTask.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousFileChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIO.read(AsyncFileIO.java:77)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AbstractFileIO$1.run(AbstractFileIO.java:82)
```

I inspected the rt.jar the server is used and found this Invoker$2.

Also I found this sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2 in the list of loaded classes in Java VisualVM.

So I don't understand at all what's the problem.

Comment: What java version do you use?

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_201-b09 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.201-b09

Comment: Have you observed exceptions somewhere above in the logs?

Comment: My bad, I didn't save the log, but I'm sure, there weren't any exceptions above. If I encounter this issue again - I'll share the entire log.